# Reverting Display Brightness Changes

Tags: pi-3, screen, ubuntu, recovery

I have Ubuntu Mate installed on RPi3 with official 7" screen.

I was changing screen brightness through Mate's GUI where I dragged the bar too much towards the dark side... Resulting BLACK LCD!!!

How can I revert this? I can remove the microSD and mount it, but not sure where settings are stores (directory /sys is empty when I mount through Windows).

Any ideas?

Comment: *"directory /sys is empty when I mount through Windows"* -> Yes, it's just a mount point for a kernel interface.  The file nodes inside while the system is running are abstractions; they aren't stored anywhere (note usually the size is 0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I check brightness level AFTER login, which is not perfect... But my device does perform auto login functionality. To make this work I must edit `/etc/sudoers.d` file like so:

```
user ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /home/user/Desktop/scripts/brightness.sh
```

And following scripts into my Startup applicaitons:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $EUID -ne 0 ]; then
    printf 'Script requires root...\n\r'
else
    path='/sys/class/backlight/rpi_backlight/'
    min=10
    max=$(< ${path}'max_brightness')
    value=$(< ${path}'brightness')

    if [ $# -ne 0 ]; then # setting value
        input=$1

        if [ $input -eq $input ] 2>/dev/null; then
            # checking for min
            if [ $input -lt $min ]; then
                input=$min
            fi

            # checking for max
            if [ $input -gt $max ]; then
                input=$max
            fi

            printf "\n\rChanging brightness to: ${input}\n\r\n\r"       
            ( echo $input | sudo tee ${path}brightness ) > /dev/null
        else
            printf '\n\rIncorrect input...\n\r\n\r'
        fi
    else # repairing black screen
        if [ $value -lt  $min ]; then
            printf '\n\rValue is too low... Increasing brightness to: '

            ( echo $max | sudo tee ${path}brightness ) > /dev/null

        else
            printf 'Brightness ok...\n\r'
        fi
    fi
fi

exit 0
```

Answer (score 2):

You could simply insert the SD card back in your RPi and try to get a signal over SSH or normal HDMI. 
After that you can activate the backlight with

```
echo 0 > /sys/class/backlight/rpi_backlight/bl_power
```

I don't know if this also works with ubuntu mate, but it worked with raspbian.

Comment: As a note for people unfamiliar with [sysfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sysfs), this will only work while the system is up and running.

Comment: This is why I mentioned that when I mount my SD card on other device it is displaying /sys as an empty folder.